# Are the other possible ways in adding or subtracting Rational Algebraic Expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions

I would like to know if there is/are other way/s in solving rational algebraic expressions.

This is what I usually do in adding or subtracting rational expressions
$$\frac{22x+7}{6x+5} - \frac{10x-3}{6x+5}$$

First, I combine like terms,
$$\frac{22x+7}{6x+5} - \frac{10x-3}{6x+5}=\frac{12x+10}{6x+5}$$

Then, I factor the numerator to see if I could cancel common factors,
$$\frac{12x+10}{6x+5}=\frac{2(6x+5)}{6x+5}=2$$

Are there other ways? Also, I'm not just asking for other ways on solving the equations above.

Thank you

Comment: You can always first cancel common factors and then add or subtracting. It's not necessarily less work.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't thought of that. But what if there were no common factors at the start?

Comment: You can always do long division, just like with numbers. In this case $\frac{22x + 7}{6x +5} = 4 - \frac{2x + 13}{6x +5}$. Advantage of this method is that expression in numerator get smaller (specifically - the order of the polynomial stay the same or becomes lower).